# Need help in converting EBCDIC to Hexadecimal

Tags: java, type-conversion, user-defined-functions, mainframe, ebcdic

I am writing an hive UDF to convert the EBCDIC character to Hexadecimal. 
Ebcdic characters are present in hive table.Currently I am able to convert it, bit it is ignoring few characters while conversion.

Example:

This is the EBCDIC value stored in table:

> AGNSAÃ±AÂ¦Ã»ÃÃÂÃÂµÂjÂqÂÂÂÂ Â Ã ()

Converted hexadecimal:

> c1c7d5e2000a5cd4f6ef99187d07067203a0200258dd9736009f000000800017112400000000001000084008403c000000000000000080

What I want as output:

> c1c7d5e200010a5cd4f6ef99187d0706720103a0200258dd9736009f000000800017112400000000001000084008403c000000000000000080

It is ignoring to convert the below EBCDIC characters:

> 01 -  It is start of heading
>   10 -  It is a escape 
>   15 -  New line.

Below is the code I have tried so far:

```
public class EbcdicToHex extends UDF {
  public String evaluate(String edata) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] ebcdiResult = getEBCDICRawData(edata);
    String hexResult = getHexData(ebcdiResult);
    return hexResult;
  }   

  public byte[] getEBCDICRawData (String edata) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] result = null;

    String ebcdic_encoding = "IBM-037"; 
    result = edata.getBytes(ebcdic_encoding);

    return result;
  }

  public String  getHexData(byte[] result){
    String output = asHex(result);
    return output;
  }

  public static String asHex(byte[] buf) {
    char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
    char[] chars = new char[2 * buf.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
      chars[2 * i] = HEX_CHARS[(buf[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
      chars[2 * i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[buf[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(chars);
  }
}
```

While converting, its ignoring few EBCDIC characters. How to make them also converted to hexadecimal?

Comment: Can you provide a hexdump of the original data?  In looking at what's provided I'd like to repeat the operation from the source file .  What you provided as your file does not render the same hex values for me.  I'm creating a new file with EBCDIC encoding and pasting your data in.  The hex values I get are: c1 c7 d5 e2 c1 66 8f c1 62 6a 66 8b 66 66 62 66 62 a0 62 91 62 98 62 62 62 62 40 62 40 66 40 4d 5d 15

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies elsewhere, I created a small testcase where I create a String based on those 3 bytes you claim to be ignored, but in my output they do seem to be converted correctly:

```
  private void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] {0x01, 0x10, 0x15};
    String str = new String(bytes, "IBM-037");

    byte[] result = getEBCDICRawData(str);

    for(byte b : result) {
      System.out.print(Integer.toString(( b & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring(1) + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(evaluate(str));
  }
```

Output:

> 01 10 15
>   011015

Based on this it seems both your `getEBCDICRawData` and `evaluate` method seem to be working correctly and makes me believe your String value may already be incorrect to start with. Could it be the String is already missing those characters? Or perhaps a long shot, but maybe the charset is incorrect? There are different EBCDIC charsets, so maybe the String is composed using a different one? Although I doubt this would make much difference for the 01, 10 and 15 bytes.

As a final remark, but probably unrelated to your problem, I usually prefer to use the encode/decode functions on the charset object to do such conversions:

```
String charset = "IBM-037";
Charset cs = Charset.forName(charset);
ByteBuffer bb = cs.encode(str);
CharBuffer cb = cs.decode(bb);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the details. I will try the above encode/decode functions and check ..